# what is datalayer.push doing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been trying to figure this out..I think data layer.push is simply updating the second amount. Could someone explain what is exactly going on here?

function dollarz() {

var amount1 = '$156.86';
var amount2 = amount1.replace("$","");
return amount2; 
}

dataLayer.push({ 
'transactionTotalNoDollar': dollarz(), 
'event': 'sendUpdateTwo' 
});

Comment: it just adds another element to the (presumed) array `dataLayer`.

Comment: what is datalayer..you need to explain many things here. For array like `datalayer = [1,2,3]`  `datalayer.push(4)` will  make `datalayer equal to [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Depends on what `dataLayer` is. Have you tried logging it? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and `console.log`.

Comment: dataLayer is probably google tag manager's standard analytics array.  dataLayer.push is normally used to add analytics data to the stack, which gets sent off to the analytics server.  If this is true @gudetama you should add the google tag manager tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

dataLayer is presumably an array, and `push` adds an additional element to the end of the array.

The object that gets pushed has two properties: one is the static `'event': 'sendUpdateTwo'`. The other property `transactionTotalNoDollar` gets its value from the result of calling `dollarz`. `dollarz` returns `'156.86', so the object that gets pushed looks like:

```
{ 
  'transactionTotalNoDollar': '156.86', 
  'event': 'sendUpdateTwo' 
}
```